# Auto-tuning tools for Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, database-tools

I am looking for  tools to auto-tuning for postgresql database. Do you know any tools for postgres like  DB2 Design Advisor in DB2, Database Tuning Advisor in Microsoft SQL Server or SQL Access Advisor in Oracle? 
Thanks for any links and ideas:).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you looking for [pgtune](https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/)?

Based on some inputs regarding hardware, it can suggest parameters for the `postgresql.conf`, so Postgres can operate with its best, based on your hardware, type of system and expected number of connections.

Comment: Thanks for info about pgtune. Do you know about other applications? I would like to compare the effects of  actions of those apps, this topic is a part of my research connected with my studies, any idea will by very helpfull.

Comment: @pmoniq, That's the only one I know of.  There may be others.

Comment: As stated in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server, you can use https://github.com/jfcoz/postgresqltuner and https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger

Comment: @frb - pgbadger did not exist when I wrote this answer, but that's a great tip.  You should add it as an answer, except this was an off-topic question, so I guess not.

Comment: Yes, unable to add a new answer.